# Pass non serializable object to screen react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to pass non serializable object to another screen in react native? Ideally i would like to pass it as a prop to screen. I dont want to use params, because it is not advisable for deep linking. Also i dont want to use redux or context because this is form data. Is there a good way to do this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Questions - 1. Why is the form data not serializeable? 2. Why does it being form data preclude the use of state management? 3. Why do you need to deep link with the form data? -- The normal way to pass data between screens is navigation params.

Comment: It is not serializable because it is is some existing library that they used in angular web app. I force rerender whenever that object changes, it is mutable object with a lot of things in it, it must be mutable because they made it for angular and it tracks changes when ever it mutates. I dont want to use state management for form because that would be messy, there are lot of forms and making it global state would create more problems than it solves. I dont need deep liking to that particulat screen, but I am afraid it might break it for others screens as well

Comment: Do you need the object to have all the extra properties in the destination screen? Are you passing the data to another instance of the form?  You won't break deep linking for other screens by using navigation params btw.